# What is the induced charge distribution on inner surface of a symmetrical conducting shell when a charge is placed off-centre?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Let us assume that we have a symmetrical conducting hollow shell with a charge $Q$ on its surface. Now let us bring a point charge $q$ inside the shell cavity and place it at any point except at the centre (let say at $x=a$ assuming that origin is at the centre. I know that this will induce negative charges on the inner surface of the shell, but how do I find the distribution of the negative charges on the inner surface?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Method of image charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges#Reflection_in_a_conducting_sphere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The well knows fact is '*Electric field inside the conductor is zero in static condition*'. Now let's suppose you put a charge $q$ somewhere inside the shell. And Say it doesn't produce any charge on the inner surface. Then If you make a gaussian surface passing through the conducting shell, there will be a non-zero flux through it. But it's not possible. Thus there must be an equal amount of charge should be induced to make the electric field inside the conductor to zero. Remember there should be no field line that passes through a shell.

More generally, if the neutral conducting shell takes an odd nonspherical
shape, we can’t say that the external field is spherically symmetric. But we can
say that the external field, whatever it may be, is independent of the location of
the point charge $q$ inside. Whatever the location, the external field equals the field
in a system where the point charge $q$ is absent and where we instead dump a total
charge $q$ on the shell (which will distribute itself in a particular manner).

---

HOW?

The conductor has free electrons. If you put a charge inside the conducting shell. The free charge inside the conductor will feel a force due to this charge and thus redistribute themselves so that there should be no field inside the conductor until the net force of charges due to this charge is zero.

---

> I know that this will induce negative charges on the inner surface of the shell, but how do I find the distribution of the negative charges on the inner surface?

The well know method to compute the field is [Method of Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges). The validity of the method of image charges rests upon a corollary of the uniqueness theorem, which states that the electric potential in a volume $V$ is uniquely determined if both the charge density throughout the region and the value of the electric potential on all boundaries are specified.

The more general method is to solve [Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) with specific boundarary condition.

Comment: The question asks for how induced charge is distributed on the inner surface.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: I get that. I was looking for a more mathematical and quantitative approach.

Comment: I added some method of finding the induced charge distribution. It's not possible to go through a detail .Refer to some book.

Comment: @AlphaDelta Doesn't the Wikipedia article on the image charge method answer your question?

Comment: @Puk I am trying to understand the method now. The question was just a thought experiment.